# Android Socket: java.net.SocketException: No route to host

Tags: sockets, tcpclient, android

I am trying to connect (through TCP) to the server running on my machine from the Android device.
I have `android.permission.INTERNET` in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

I am able to connect using emulator but trying from the device throws an error:
`Android Socket: java.net.SocketException: No route to host`

Can anyone please help.

Comment: How do you access your computer from the device? By Wi-Fi or USB? What IP do you use to connect to the computer from Android?

Comment: hi, I ma using WIFI. Ip address is what I am getting using ipconfig: IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.114

Comment: Can you reach for example web-server started on your computer (using Browser on your phone)? If no - then it is a network configuration issue, not a programming one.

Comment: when I try in my browser http://192.168.1.114:55555 it shows blank page(expected). SO I dont think this is n/w issue. Is this related to firewall ?

Comment: Why is blank page expected? Can you start web-server on your computer (Tomcat or IIS) and access it from the device Browser? Also check on your router whether Android device has received IP address in the same subnet as your computer.

Answer (score 22):

Disabled wifi on my Android device and then re-enabled it and it worked.

Comment: worked for me too ... I was trying to test what happens when my app lost network and can it retrry again so I stopped the router then restarted again and then I got this issue, it was not solved until I disabled and enabled again the mobile wifi

Comment: Don't know why ... don't know how but THIS WORKED you LEGEND LOVEU

Answer (score 6):

Your 192.168.1.114 address is a DHCP address (dynamically) assigned by your router to your PC. As a result it is visible to the emulator.

But depending on how your WiFi is set up, the Android is probably on a different router / subnet and can't see 192.168.1.114. You could check that by typing 192.168.1.114 into the address bar of the Android browser.

If 192.168.1.114 is not visible to your Android, then you will have to either change the routing rules on your router to make it visible, or add a DNS lookup for it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems. It turned out my Win7 firewall was blocking the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with my android app running IP address of the computer. The app was working good and then suddenly volley started throwing exceptions. I tried enabling and disabling my mobile wifi and it didn't work. Then I tried shutting down my main router and turning back on. And just like that volley was happy and the app started working again:)

Hope that helps.