# Android, PHP and MySQL: URLConnection no route to host

Tags: php, android, mysql, urlconnection

I have been following this basic [tutorial](http://androidcss.com/android/android-php-mysql-login-tutorial/) to learn Android, PHP and MySQL.

As I have been following I have also been adapting the code to suit my needs.

Everything has worked great so far, and I am assuming my code is correct (client-side anyway) as the App runs fine, and no Java errors appear in the logcat. The only issue I am having at the minute is the following:

```
libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
```

When I press the login button, its runs through the entire Method to the end.

Here is my LoginActivity.java code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
EditText emailLogin, passwordLogin;
Button buttonLogin, buttonRegisterLink;
TextView numberAttemptsLeft;
int counter = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    emailLogin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_login);
    passwordLogin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_login);
    buttonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_login);
    buttonRegisterLink = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_register_link);
    numberAttemptsLeft = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numberAttemptsLeft);
    numberAttemptsLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // method calls
    login();
    linkToRegisterScreen();
}

public void login() {
    final String email = emailLogin.getText().toString();
    final String password = passwordLogin.getText().toString();

    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new AsyncLogin().execute(email,password);
        }
    });
}

private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    ProgressDialog loading = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        loading.setCancelable(false);
        loading.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            url = new URL("http://myIPaddress/api/login.php");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("email", params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter("password", params[1]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            connection.connect();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }

        try {
            int response_code = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                return(result.toString());
            }else{
                return("unsuccessful");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        loading.dismiss();

        if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Email or Password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something else went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am using WAMP, and the folder "api" is saved under the "www" folder. login.php is saved within the "api" folder.

I have tried the solutions suggested on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905505/android-socket-java-net-socketexception-no-route-to-host) but I have had no luck.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Code from my two PHP files in case it helps.

configuration.php (under api/include)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$database = "db";

try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host = $servername; dbname = $db", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die("Server Error.");
    }
?>
```

login.php (under api)

```
<?php
include 'configuration.php';

// check whether or not the email or password is set from android
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    // initialize variables
    $result='';
    $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

    // query database
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = :email AND password = :password';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

    // if else statement
    if($stmt->rowCount())
        {
        $result="true"; 
        }  
        elseif(!$stmt->rowCount())
        {
        $result="false";
        }

    // send the result back to android
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it's something wrong with the server that is making it unreachable. Do you get a server response or does it error out? Where is the exception being thrown?

Comment: It just errors out. java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /myIPaddress (port 80) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)

Comment: Are you able to hit the url through a browser on the device or through your computer?

Comment: Yes, I can go to that link no problem. It is giving me two warnings though about my PHP files. Will I edit the question to include the PHP files?

Comment: I'm not sure if the php code is the problem (although the warnings wouldn't hurt). If there was an issue with the PHP files, your android code would still work. The error looks like the android application has an issue reaching the site at all. Try changing the URL to a known one, like google.com and make sure you're able to reach that through the app.

Comment: Warning: include(configuration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\api\login.php on line 2

Comment: Warning: include(): Failed opening 'configuration.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\api\login.php on line 2

Comment: That's the two warnings.

Comment: Is that on your computer or on the device browser you see this ?

Comment: Your include isn't working. I haven't worked with PHP in a few years so I can't recall if a failed include would cause reachability problems, but it's clearly saying line 2, it can not find configuration.php. There is a directory issue on your server.

Try reaching the server on a device other than what is hosting the server, or else you'll get false positives. Check to see if you get the same results of going to login.php w/ post data on the browser of the device which is running the app. If you're not able to hit it on the device browser, it's an app issue. Otherwise the it's the server.

Comment: include 'include/configuration.php'; could that resolve it?

Comment: No problem. I will give that a try tomorrow as I have to go to work soon. Cheers for the pointers.

Comment: When I go to that link I get a blank page (as expected, I think), but still no joy with connection. Same problem as before.